# Traveling with expired passport and Visa in same country

Tags: usa

My passport is expired and US Visa also expired can I travel to different state of USA with expired passport of my home country and expired Visa of USA?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are inside the US, the expiry of your visa is not relevant anymore. What governs is your *immigration status* which was determined when you entered, and may be longer or shorter than your visa.

As far as government rules is concerned, traveling between states does not require passports any more than crossing the street does.

Depending on your way of traveling, you may need to present some *identification* (in particular, if you're *flying*, airlines and airport security will require this), and if the expired passport was the only government-issued ID you had, that can be a problem. But again, that will be the same whether you're flying between states, or within a single state.

Comment: And, if you're driving within 100 miles of a land border, be prepared to be stopped occasionally at CBP checkpoints where they will inspect your documents.